# Collapsing Toolbar with ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout

When I collapse `Toolbar`, `ListView` appearance is half.It just looks like square. However, I want to see all of them. It should extend downward. `ListView` might have a problem. How can I solve this problem? In addition,

If you don't understand, I attached this problem in image. You will understand easily!
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7NrZ.png)

**EDIT :** Actually, `ImageView` is normally wider but it seems wrong here because I collapse it. When it is full, square appearance of `ListView` is like image.

MY XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example./////">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/climbing"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lstTask"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="287dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:src="@drawable/edit"
    app:backgroundTint="#6666ff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    android:id="@+id/action_add"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/savedHabits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:backgroundTint="#6666ff"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Just fixed the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

1. add `CustomListView`

   ```
   public class CustomListView extends ListView {

   public CustomListView(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
   }

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
   public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2
           , MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
       super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
   }
   }
   ```
2. change xml code

**You change this.**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstTask"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="287dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
```

**To**

```
<!-- your package name-->
<com.your.app.utils.CustomListView
    android:id="@+id/lstTask"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you！

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it when you add attribute 
android:fillViewport="true" 
in android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

This is my code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/titlesListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout >
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

It works like a magic.