# ListView overlaps Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I used to setup a Collapsing Toolbar with the Project-Template from Android Studio and tried to implement a ListView in the NestedScrollView (see code below)

I have the newest Android Studio Version and AVD runs on Android 9

I allready tried to

1. change `android:fillViewport="true"` of the NestedScrollView
2. implement my own ListView ([Collapsing Toolbar with ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538115/collapsing-toolbar-with-listview))
3. wrap ListView into a LinearLayout

I found several solutions using a `RecyclerView`, I do not want to use this approach - If this is the last way to do it, I will ;). (This is for a school project and we should only use components we have learned in school *face palm*)

I will skip a few XML Import Lines in the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainScreen">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="net.mountdev.alcohollevel.EntryList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

NestedListView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainScreen"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main_screen">

        <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The current result is, that the ListView is in the ActionBar which should no be (see screenshot)

[image: ActionBar overlaps with List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `fragment`. It taking the whole space. Try something like

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

and inside your `AppBarLayout` use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

for your `fragment` add `android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"`

Comment: Thank you! ListView is now under the Toolbar but only showing one Element (?). Also the floatingActionButton moved to the top left (if think this can be fixed later).

Comment: for the floating button add to it android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"     and for elements that might be because of scrollview change it to something else